# Initialize pointer to struct inside another struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I have two pointer variables (`prevGuiMsg` and `currGuiMsg`) to a struct inside another struct definition in a C++ source-file:

```
typedef struct
{
    bool re_pop_required;
    bool concurrent_popups;
    MlGuiMsg* prevGuiMsg;
    MlGuiMsg* currGuiMsg;
    uint32_t first_popup;
    uint32_t second_popup;
}RePopup;
```

The `M1GuiMsg`-struct is defined inside a different C header-file (I'm mixing C and C++ code). A pointer to the struct is passed as an argument to a function in the source file, where I wish to store the data that the parameter points to in the pointer variables `prevGuiMsg` and `currGuiMsg`.

I wish to *explicitly* declare a variable of the type struct `RePopup` and initialize its members along with the declaration in the C++ source file:

```
RePopup rp = {false, false, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

My question is therefore: can/should one initialize a pointer to a struct with zero inside the explicit declaration of another struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `nullptr` rather than `0` but otherwise there is nothing wrong with initialising a pointer to 0.

Comment: What is the advantage of using nullptr rather than 0?

Comment: If he's using C++11 or newer, yes.

Comment: @AbdelAleem It wouldn't make a technical difference for directly initializing a pointer member like this, but it can make a difference in some cases involving overloaded functions and/or templates.  So it's a good practice to use it by default for all pointers, and it also makes the intent of the code clearer.

Comment: It means you are being explicit that you are null initialising a pointer. Also you will get an error if you accidentally try to assign `nullptr` to an integer. e.g. if you mistyped your initialiser as `{false, false, 0, nullptr, nullptr, 0}` it wont compile

Comment: @AbdelAleem Self-documentingness only in this particular case, but it's a good habit generally.

Comment: @thomas_f - Using C++11 or newer may not have been a valid assumption at 2012. At 2019 it's not unreasonable to assume it. Generally, the consensus on SO is that unless the OP says so themselves, one can assume a fairly modern standard revisions is being used.